# DataGridColumn width forces maximum width of parent when inside GridSplitter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, gridsplitter

I was trying to create a window that is split into two sections like such:

[image: DataGrid inside GridSplitter]

What I noticed is that there are some properties which seem to conflict with eachother.  Namely:

- The `Window.Width` property.
- The `ColumnDefinition.MinWidth` property (especially for the 3rd column)
- The `DataGridTextColumn.Width="*"` property.

Using the properties values defined in the below XAML, I noticed that the width of the last `DataGridTextColumn` causes the parent `Grid` to expand to the maximum permitted value taking into account the right-side `Grid`'s minimum width.
My expectation, however, was that `DataGridTextColumn` would fill the remaining *available* space as constrained by the `DataGrid`.

I also noticed that this expanding/pushing behavior caused by the `DataGridTextColumn` only happens for certain values for the `ColumnDefinition.MinWidth` and `Window.Width` properties (which can be also be resized in runtime for 'odd' behavior).

I would like each top-level `Grid` (the left and the right `Grids` that sit next to the `GridSplitter`) to have a minimum width, and default widths of 70% and 30% of the window respectively.  But I'd also like the last column in the `DataGrid` to fill the remaining region. **How can I achieve this with without the DataGrid pushing outside its bounds?**

```
<Window x:Class="GridSplitterTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridSplitterTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7*" MinWidth="160"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" MinWidth="155"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <!-- This is the left Grid -->
            <DataGrid Margin="10">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" MinWidth="60"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2" MinWidth="60"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column3" MinWidth="60"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column4 (Fill)" MinWidth="90" Width="*"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="6" Background="Red"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <!-- This is the right Grid -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused, when you say "My expectation, however, was that DataGridTextColumn would fill the remaining available space as constrained by the DataGrid." Doesn't it? Your DataGrid has no width specification, so it stretches to the size of the containing Grid, which should fill up 70% of your horizontal window width. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "remaining region". How is your desired result different than your screenshot?

Comment: I'll try to clear it up.  I typically thing top-down as far as layout goes.  The window has a width.  I was 70% of the width to be given to the left grid.  The left grid contains a DataGrid that stretches to the grid's dimensions (with a small margin).  Then the column should fill the remaining width that the DataGrid uses.

Comment: EDIT:  The screenshot is correct, but when you run and try the code out, you will notice that the GridSplitter is pushed all the way to the right.  This appears to be caused by setting the DataGrid's column to "*".  So the problem lies in the behavior/usability of the interface.

Comment: That's just the thing, I tried your xaml as-is and I see the layout in your screenshot. The grid splitter is not pushed all the way to the right. What OS are you testing in?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit (.NET 4.5.2).  To test, I needed to run the XAML then attempt to move the splitter left.  I found that instead of moving left, the splitter forcibly goes back to the right.